# php manage tabulation and breakline output file

Tags: php, output, shell-exec

I would like to execute a perl command line inside my php code but it seems not interpreting "\t" as tabulation and "\n" as breakline inside the output file.

Perl command:

```
perl -ane 'print join("\t",@F[0,1,1])."\n" unless(m/^#/)' snvs.vcf > fpfilter/snvs.var
```

My php Code:

```
<?php
$workingDir='testa-tum';
$sample='snvs';
shell_exec('perl -ane "print join("\t",@F[0,1,1])."\n" unless(m/^#/)" /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/'.$workingDir.'/'.$sample.'.vcf > /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/'.$workingDir.'/'.$sample.'.var');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally found I gotta to use `\"\t\"` and \"\n\"